# Isolated audio without a transformer

Tags: audio, ac, isolation, bias, ground-loop

I'm putting together a guitar pedal for splitting the signal to two different amps. One of the features I want to put in is a 'ground-lift'; isolating the signal to avoid ground loops between the two different loads.

The traditional way to do that is with the following simple method: a suitable transformer...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fngMA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I don't know how much I trust the transformer to not colour the signal, and I don't mind doing a bit of over-engineering to avoid using one.

I'm more trusting of op-amps and AC-coupling using series capacitors, so I figured the following might be a good workaround:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF4vvf.png)</sup>

The load-side of the AC-coupling capacitor is biased by an supply isolated from the source and fed into a buffer.
Is there any reason this wouldn't work the way I think it would?

Comment: FWIW, optocoupler or even a capacitor can give you galvanic isolation too. Wikipedia covers it quite well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation

Comment: @vaxquis Although there are various methods of galvanic isolation, the trick here is to do it whilst retaining a high-fidelity analogue signal

Comment: Have you considered analog to digital conversion, digital isolation and digital to analog conversion?

Comment: @EricJohnson I have indeed! I can use a ADC and DAC and link them by a standardized hardware interface that I can optically isolate. It is very possible and wouldn't cost too much, but I wanted to do it by simple analogue means if possible. I may include this option as part of the over-engineering principle of getting the result i want

Comment: Check out the technical papers at www.thatcorp.com. They have a diff. amp chip and output driver ic that looks like perhaps could do what you are looking for. I'm checking into this myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any reason this wouldn't work the way I think it would?

You cannot expect that circuit to work because the guitar signal ground connection has to connect into the op-amp circuit ground node and without that connection you are just going to get noise. The impact of this is that you are not therefore isolating the two receiver circuits as you previously wished would happen.

Try using fully differential amplifiers such as Instrumentattion Amplifiers but, don't expect miracles - IA's can isolate quite well but only within the voltage range of their respective power rails. In other words, if receive circuit A is offset from receive circuit B by a few volts to a few tens of volts you will hit problems.

True galvanic isolation (up to several hundred volts) is acheivable by using magnetics and therefore transformers.

Comment: Darn, I hoped it would work. Thanks for defining possible solutions. I'm glad to hear there are other options, though not without their own drawbacks.

Comment: I'd go with an audio transformer for simplicity and bear in mind that a lot of (if not all) tube amplifiers use transformers on their output stages. The distortion that they *might* bring to the party won't be significant. Try looking up Hammond audio transformers and go for ones with a decent high frequency performance but, if connecting the raw geetar output to the primary I'd use a buffer amplifier and a transformer with dual isolated secondaries; one for each signal chain.

Answer (score 5):

This is a circuit I designed several decades ago to do just what you want. I had two pieces of equipment with slightly different ground environment, and wanted to pass a high fidelity signal between them.

Normally, I would use a differential signal, with a differential receiver. However, the existing receiver, which I couldn't modify, had a solid, ground referenced, single-ended input, and all I could play with was the transmitter.

The actual circuit is identical to a differential amplifier, with the connections taken to slightly different places. The amplifier senses the voltage of the remote ground, and adds it to the signal being transmitted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOfvpg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The normal differential amplifier rules apply to the R1/2/3/4 values.

The reversed biassed diodes are for protection, in case the cable is unplugged and the shield subject to a large signal, they would not normally conduct up to a few hundred mV of ground offset.

This is not isolation in the true sense, especially with the protection diodes which will allow a fault in one to blow a fuse in the other, but it does break ground loops, reject inter-ground noise, and allow a ground lift functionality.

There is a way to use optocouplers to give a DC coupled, truly isolated, reasonable distortion analogue link between equipments. While a single optocoupler is rarely linear enough for audio signals, a pair run under the same conditions, one used as feedback for the driving signal, can track well enough to reduce the distortion to useable levels. There are even 'dual receiver' optoisolators for just this purpose. However, this would need an isolated power supply in the sender, otherwise the input to the next equipment would be a special purpose current signal, so not a general purpose input.

Tales of missed opportunity. Many years before audio noise-shaped sigma delta converters were well known, about the time Phillips and Sony were filing patents, I was also investigating the concept. One application I envisaged was a high speed sigma delta ADC driving one bit in the 1M to 10M range down cheap optical fibre to another equipment, with the reconstruction filter simply an RC filter. Total isolation, high fidelity audio, and cheap, a sort of analog Toslink. But I had other fish to fry. Fairly easy to build if you want, either from discretes (HC logic plus opamps), or there are sigma delta modulators available.

Comment: So in this method the op-amp isn't actually strictly isolated, but will provide correction to the signal, and (as @Andyaka mentioned) will work where the output signal voltage is within power rails of the op-amp?

Comment: @Joe Yes, it's not isolated in the 'won't get a shock from it if there's a problem', but it is isolated in the 'ground lift' and 'breaks ground loops' sense.

Comment: @Joe Added two 'real isolation' options to my answer. Are either of interest?

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because the supply is isolated so the grounds will float according to the signal as well. As the signal path is isolated, no signal current passes through the capacitor, so the op-amp sees no signal.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I don't know how much I trust the transformer to not colour the signal, and I don't mind doing a bit of over-engineering to avoid using one.

For completeness' sake: there are isolation amplifiers, which are analog input to analog output, but galvanically isolated. Their intended purpose is not audio but sensing small voltage differences in high-voltage systems.
Consider the [AMC1311](http://www.ti.com/product/AMC1311) from TI. It has a typical output bandwidth of 220kHz (which is plenty), truly galvanically isolates the input from the output for up to 7000V difference, but "only" has 82.6dB SNR.

However, the further you peek into audiophile/"overengineering" territory, the more people prefer passive transformers like those from [Lundahl](https://www.lundahltransformers.com/audiophile/) to active circuitry. So the question "How do I isolate my sound when budget is no limit", the answer may after all be a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

The time honoured way to do this (in the analogue domain) is to convert your line level signal to [balanced audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio). (This means that the signal from your guitar first has to go through a preamp with a suitably high impedance input, generally 470k to 1M or so, and with a proper balanced output.) Now, no direct ground connection is required in the signal path.

Isolation can then be provided by placing DC block caps in series with the line connections. However in a professional environment this is generally considered to be inferior to high quality audio transformers, as can be purchased from suppliers such as Lundahl, Sowter and Jensen. These products do provide superb galvanic isolation along with very high audio quality, and other benefits such as excellent rejection of common mode induced noise, when properly configured. They aren't cheap - but may not in fact be a bad investment when you factor in the simplicity of design, reliability and so on.

(To understand why transformers provide better isolation than a pair of blocking caps, consider the effect of a common mode transient with a fast edge between the tx and rx side. With caps there will be corresponding transient currents which will probably be of unequal magnitude, due to capacitor tolerances and so on. A transformer is a n inherently symmetrical design, and so such a transient has much less chance of creating an audible artifact.)

These days, of course, other solutions such as moving to digital domain and using a fibre link exist, but I question whether the complexity is justifiable for your application (as well as, perhaps, issues with reliability, latency and so on).

Really it's a question of horses for courses.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to not use a transformer, one possible solution is to use a isolation power supply for your amplifier circuit.

However, your design is not going to work because you didn't isolate the ground. The whole point of using an isolated power supply is to isolate both the ground and power.

A true isolation power supply will have two input, power and ground, and two (or more) output, power and another ground.

The output ground is completely floating, aka it can be any voltage the other circuit requires. So when you connect your amplifier to the input, your amplifier ground will be **exactly** the same as input. Thus, no noise.

Having single or dual rail supply is a different problem from this isolation issue, however.  After isolation, you can easily make a single rail work like a dual rail. You simply make a virtual ground at half of rail voltage by Zener diode (a resistive divider can work, but it will bd noisy and it will inject power rail noise into audio signals.)

One issue to point out here is usually an isolation power supply might be more costy than an audio isolation transformer depending on how much power you need.